# Having a table use textwidth and still have centered text?

Tags: tables

I'm wondering if it's possible to have a table in LaTeX that spans the entire textwidth, and that the columns automatically center themselves... I have tried using the "X" option in `tablerx`, but it doesn't center the columns...

Additionally, you'll see that I place two `\hline`s below my first row. Is it possible to put a little space below **the line**?

Code below.

```
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Unit comparison between reduced Lennard-Jones units and GROMACS dimensional units.  \vspace{0.2cm}}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X X X X}

\hline \hline %\vspace{0.1cm}
    \bf{Unit}          &              \bf{Lennard-Jones}              &             \bf{Dimensional}          &       \bf{GROMACS units} \\ \hline 
    Time             &                    1 $t^*$                       &                   1 ps                  &                     ps              \\ 
    Velocity        &                    1 $v^*$                      &                1000 m/s            &                   ps/nm          \\
    Temperature &                  1 $T^*$                      &                120.272 K          &                        K
\\ \hline \hline
\end{tabularx}
\label{table:properties}
\end{table}
```

Comment: change the `X` to `>{\centering\arraybackslash}X` to center the text in each column and add `\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}` before the table to pad the rows a bit

Comment: oh don't use `\begin{table}[h]` unless you really have to, it makes it highly likely the table goes to the end of the document, use `[htp]`

Comment: Remember that `\bf` is an obsolete command: use `\textbf`. By the way, `\bf` is a declaration, so if you use it that way, you'll find all text in boldface. It's not a problem in a table cell, which forms a group, but it would be in normal text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I added a commented version of your code below. Please in future always post *complete* documents including the preamble and necessary packages etc. It makes it a lot easier to test the code.

```
\begin{table}[htp]% not h om its own
\caption{Unit comparison between reduced Lennard-Jones units and GROMACS dimensional units.  \vspace{0.2cm}}


  \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}% centering
 \setlength\extrarowheight{3pt} % extra padding
  %\bf does not take an argument, and has been deprecated
  % since latex2ecame out in 1993 use \textbf

 \noindent % otherwise the line will be too wide by \parindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{C C C C}

\hline \hline 
    \textbf{Unit}          &              \textbf{Lennard-Jones}              &             \textbf{Dimensional}          &       \textbf{GROMACS units} \\ \hline 
    Time             &                    1 $t^*$                       &                   1 ps                  &                     ps              \\ 
    Velocity        &                    1 $v^*$                      &                1000 m/s            &                   ps/nm          \\
    Temperature &                  1 $T^*$                      &                120.272 K          &                        K
\\ \hline \hline
\end{tabularx}
\label{table:properties}
\end{table}
```

Comment: My apologies for not posting the complete source.. I still can if needed.  Let me try out your solution.

Comment: Everything worked!  Thank you so much.  Didn't know about the `htp` either!

Comment: Are you sure one needs the `\noindent` instruction? (Isn't `\parindent` equal 0 inside a table float?)

Comment: @Mico oh yes actually that's true thanks. Doesn't do any harm though:-)

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the `tabu` package instead of `tabularx` and define your table as follows:

```
\tabulinesep=1.5pt
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {X[c] X[c] X[c] X[c]} 
   \hline \hline 
   \rowfont[c]\bfseries %will apply the \bfseries command to all elements of the next row
   Unit & Lennard-Jones & Dimensional & GROMACS units \\ 
   \hline 
   Time & 1 $t^*$ & 1 ps & ps \\ 
   Velocity & 1 $v^*$ & 1000 m/s & ps/nm \\
   Temperature & 1 $T^*$  & 120.272 K & K \\ 
   \hline \hline
\end{tabu}
```

You will need to add to your preamble `\usepackage{tabu}`

The `\tabulinesep` bit increases the space between lines (both above and below).

The way the syntax works for the `X` Column in `tabu` is `X[<width modifier>,<column modifiers>]` where the column modifiers can be `l, c, r, j, L, C, R, J` (left, centered, right, justified) with the default set to `j`. There are many more options in the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tabu/tabu.pdf).